# Working with categorized Views with totals in Lotus Notes Designer

Tags: lotus-notes, formula, lotus

I have two forms with two views. That needs to access data from one another.

I have a view that has been categorized and computes the total value per data. My problem now is, on a separate view, I need to extract the subtotals from view #1.

For Example;

On View #1, I have columns named Country (C1), State/City (SC) and Population (P1). So I have multiple State/City that are categorized by Country.

On View #2, I have columns named Country (C2) (different field name from View #1) and Population 2009 (P2).

Now I need to get the total from View #1 per Country. That needs to appear side by side on the same level as View #2 and do subtraction on the 3rd column. I can't seem to rack my brain how to do it. Since I'm using two different forms.

Sample View:

View #1 (taken from Form #1)

Country  State  P1

Japan
Tokyo 100
Kyoto 150  Yokohama 200

450 (total computed by Lotus Notes)

Philippines 
Manila 100 Cebu 200

300 (total computed by Lotus Notes)

View #2 (taken from Form #2, except Population 2010 (P1))

Country  P2  P1
Japan 200  450

Philippines 200  300

Hope you guys can help me. I'm a newbie in this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obligatory: "aaaaaaargh! Lotus Notes!"

Answer (score 4):

You don't state the client version or whether this is for the web or not, but in a "vanilla" Lotus Notes client application, one view cannot reference the content of another. End of story. So you need to think around what it is you're doing, and how else you can accomplish this. One approach would be to store the totals data in the document(s) referenced in view 2.

For example, if you structure your design so that you have a "summary" document for each country, this could then be updated from view 1 (with the country / state data) by doing a simple view "skim" (check Designer help on `NotesViewEntryCollection` and related classes). You would then reference these summary documents in view 2.

If you are using XPages in the Notes client (i.e. you're on 8.5 and above), then you can perform view "joins" of a sort (you can present a data view, and have that view perform look-ups elsewhere). I will leave someone else to explain that if it's an option for you.